# How do I get div to show when user enters restricted character in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hello :) I have a form with an input that I have restricted the characters that can be used using jQuery. I would like for a div to display next to or under the input field if a restricted character is pressed.

So far I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#15').keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
      return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    $(codeBlock).appendTo($('#15'));
    return false;
  });
});
```

With codeBlock being a variable containing HTML. I can see the HTML in the page source but it isn't actually displaying it and places it under "Shadow Content" which sounds cool but doesn't help me any. It is appending it in the right place, just not showing it.

I've been working on this longer than I'd like to admit. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated. Have a great day!

```js
const codeBlock = '<div>' +
  '<h1>I said only numbers and letters</h1>' +
  '</div>';

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#15').keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
      return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    $(codeBlock).appendTo('#15');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_15" id="15" type="text" value="" class="medium " placeholder="Only letters and numbers allowed">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you add a fully-reproducible example, so that we can run your code and see it working in a code snippet?  This makes it significantly easier to debug to have a sandbox demo.

Comment: Sure...how do I do that? haha, I'm sorry for being a noob.

Comment: Sure thing!  It's the `< >` icon in the edit-form.  You'll get four sections, one for html, one for js, one for css, and one to view output.

Comment: and you can choose jQuery from the drop down once you're in the code snippet screen too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

- [**`append()`**](https://api.jquery.com/append/) inserts the code as a child, so your `<input />` elements was becoming `<input>(yourmessage)</input>`.  Use [**`insertAfter()`**](https://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) instead.
- You had your jQuery selector for changing as `$(codeBlock).append('#15');`.  That should have been `$('#15')`, not `'#15'`, and since we're in an event handler, let's just use `this` instead, since it's even more clear: `$(codeBlock).append(this)`.

Works for me:

```js
const codeBlock = '<div>' +
  '<h1>I said only numbers and letters</h1>' +
  '</div>';

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#15').keypress(function(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
      return true;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    $(codeBlock).insertAfter(this);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="input_15" id="15" type="text" value="" class="medium " placeholder="Only letters and numbers allowed">
```